# Another user deleted migration files

Tags: ruby-on-rails, migration

I was working on a rails application with another user who wasn't confident with rails at the time. The person accidentally deleted a few migration files, now when I try in to deploy the app on a new machine the migration's can not run correctly is it possible to generate the migration files based on models etc..

Any help would be appreciated

Thanks....

Comment: You can load schema.rb with rake: `rake db:schema:load`. Be careful it deletes production data.

Comment: What version control do you use? You might revert changes that deleted migration files.

Comment: `rake db:schema:load` will purge whatever you have on your db though

Comment: The database records are backed up at a different location. I haven't used version control with this app as teaching the other user rails was enough for one day :p

Comment: Next time you should give your students a copy of your app ;)

Comment: Was a friend not a student but yeah i agree yoshiji... rookie mistake lol

Comment: if you really don't have those files in your version control may be you could re-create them migration files manually? `diff` your `schema.rb` or `structure.sql` (assuming yours is the correct version) with the version that is missing some migrations to get all the differences. `rake db:migrate:status` will show you all the migration IDs if you need to put your migrations in order again.

Answer (score 1):

As Marek said, assuming you use version control, you can go back to where those changes were made and revert that commit.

If you're not using version control, then I think you just received a great lesson in why you should be using version control :)